# I have Two buttons in a list item, how to get which button is clicked in ExpendableListview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, custom-adapter

I Have a Expendable Listview that a have product list in its child. And every child have two button for add to cart and remove for particular product.
How can i know which product user wants to add.

Answer (score 0):

use this method in your adapter

```
private void sendMessage(String duration, String puStatus) {
        Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
        Intent intent = new Intent("updateDuration");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra("duration", duration);
        intent.putExtra("puStatus", puStatus);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
 }
```

use this code in your activity

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            String duration = intent.getStringExtra("duration");
            String puStatus = intent.getStringExtra("puStatus");


            Utilz.printLog("BroadcastReceiver", "Got message: " + duration + " puStatus " + puStatus);
        }
    };
```

register receiver in your activity like this

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("updateDuration"));
```

Comment: Tell me about how can i use interface and broadcast recciver

Comment: see my updated answer, it is localbroadcastmanager which will broadcast your data, you can pass flag or anything like string to know about which button is clicked..

Comment: Thanks for help me .

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, i think that if you have your buttons inside xml layout file, you can add an id for each button.

And when you go to process what button is clicked, you can match the id of clicked button with the id of layout.

Hope this help.